# How to apply an anonymous function inside dplyr mutate pipeline in a rowwise manor?

Tags: r, dplyr

A trivial reproducible example is presented below, I want to mutate the `mtcars` dataframe at variables
`vs` and `vm` such that if the value is equal to 1 it is changed to 2. Below is my original approach, which produces error `the condition has length > 1`. So obviously it's not iterating through each element in the vector.

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(vs,am),function(x) {if(x == 1){x <- 2}})
```

My second approach was to try a `lapply` to iterate over each element in the vector, which also gave me an error `Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default`.

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(vs,am),lapply(function(x) {if(x == 1){x <- 2}}))
```

I obviously know how to accomplish this in a for loop, just want to understand the logic behind the scenes.

Comment: Notice that `mutate_at` is superseded!

Comment: Ok, so just use `mutate(across(...))` instead, I assume from the answer below.

Comment: Yes, @ChrisOosthuizen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
mtcars %>%
    mutate(across(c(vs, am), ~ case_when(.x == 1 ~ 2, TRUE ~ .x)))
```

Comment: Thanks, definitely one solution. What is the `~` in the solution? I'm assuming it's linked to `x.` as an element of the vector? Furthermore, if you are forced to use a anonymous function (not `case_when`), how would that look?

Comment: `~` is the way to write `purrr`-style anonymous functions. `.x` is used to refer to the function parameter (in this case the vectors we mutate across, i.e. `vs` and `am`). If you don't like this style, simply write `function(x)` explicitly instead of `~`